# Неверное отображение графика AreaChart

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть FlowPane который динамически формируется, при посещении вкладки Tab

```
 public FlowPane getFlowpaneGrafic(){

    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("ODDS");

    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    yAxis.setLabel("Count");

    AreaChart stackedAreaChart = new AreaChart(xAxis, yAxis);
    stackedAreaChart.setMinSize(1000,450);



    XYChart.Series dataSeries1 = new XYChart.Series();
    dataSeries1.setName("Surplus");

    for(XYChart.Data<Integer,Integer> data : ListXY.getSurplus()){
        dataSeries1.getData().add(data);
    }
    stackedAreaChart.getData().add(dataSeries1);  // добавление граф1



    XYChart.Series dataSeries2 = new XYChart.Series();
    dataSeries2.setName("Shortage");

    for(XYChart.Data<Integer,Integer> data : ListXY.getShortage()){
        dataSeries2.getData().add(data);
    }
    stackedAreaChart.getData().add(dataSeries2); // добавление граф2


    FlowPane box = new FlowPane();
    box.getChildren().add(stackedAreaChart);
    return box;
}
```

**А вот собственно сама проблема :**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку....

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, список должен быть сортирован по осе Х.
Мне помогло.